# Ruby Mandrill API Returning an Error in Terminal

Tags: ruby, bash, api, rubygems, mandrill

ran into a little stump just now, been doing some pair programming trying to debug it and seen scouring over google and yet found no results.

Alright, so I am building a simple mail sender app with the Mandrill API in Ruby. I believe I have my bash profile set up correctly with the API key however when I execute the .rb file through the terminal i get this message:

```
Taimurs-MacBook-Pro:mail_sender taimurknaziri$ ruby mandrill.rb 
D, [2014-06-19T12:00:30.473457 #3662] DEBUG -- : Net::NTLM is not available. Install via gem install rubyntlm.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mandrill-0.0.4/lib/mandrill/api.rb:35:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
    from mandrill.rb:3:in `new'
    from mandrill.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

After trying to debug the problem with a professor I am getting this:

```
Taimurs-MacBook-Pro:mail_sender taimurknaziri$ ruby mandrill.rb 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/mandrill-api-1.0.51/lib/mandrill.rb:28:in `initialize': You must provide a Mandrill API key (Mandrill::Error)
    from mandrill.rb:3:in `new'
    from mandrill.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

If someone could point me in the right direction as to what this means, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Your API key wouldn't go in your bash profile.  Create another file in your ruby project say `.env` and in there you can store your environment variables such as your api key, like so:

```
ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'] = "PUT YOUR KEY HERE"
```

Then you set your API key in your `mandrill.rb` program equal to `MANDRILL_API_KEY`.  As an example you could do:

```
m = Mandrill::API.new(MANDRILL_API_KEY)
```